# Tried to install package, got "Error during download request: Not found"

Tags: helm, package

This is when I was trying to install helm-projectile package via `M-x package-install`. What's this mean? How do I resolve?

Answer (score 2):

I dug up the answer in [this thread](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/issues/296).

Run

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
```

The [attached XKCD](http://xkcd.com/979/) inspired me to make this Q&A on StackExchange.